# External javascript not working on webmatrix using PHP at server side

Tags: javascript, php

I have just started with server side programming with PHP. I am using Microsoft Webmatrix for development. The problem is that external javascript file is not working, although embedded code is working fine. I have tried changing the file extension from index.html to index.php but no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Learning PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" name="myForm" target="_blank" onsubmit="">
   <label for="first-name">First Name: </label>
   <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="John" id="first-name"/>
   <label for="last-name">Last Name: </label>
   <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Doe" id="last-name"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add the javascript code from `script.js`?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome. It is working fine after several refreshes. I don't know what went wrong though syntax was correct. But it got fixed now.